# Drawing one camera image into another main camera image in THREE.JS

Tags: canvas, three.js, fabricjs

I am implementing a design that based on the selected coordinated x,y pixels,I need to replace image which is plane geometry into another image(Main image).I am facing problem on how to do it.

I have selected coordinated x,y pixels but i want to draw one image on selected coordinated region in threejs

I am new to this technology.if i get with the example code i will very thankful to you.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please, read carefully [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @prisoner849 Hi its nice to see the usefull information from you.I will make correction on it.Thanks.

Comment: I saw some example code below
    shape = new THREE.Shape();
    shape .moveTo(0.97780502,-1.9777799999999388);
    shape .lineTo(0.97780502,-1.9777799999999388);
is that helps me to apply pixels values which already have. But i am having problem of applying image in that selected pixel coodinated region.